# GitHub pages - Bootstrap not working properly

Tags: bootstrap-4, github-pages

I put my project on github pages, all seems to work well except interactions within the page. For example, slideshow buttons do not work, in responsive mode the burger menu does not respond, in gallery you can’t open an image to see it in full size, etc.

I can’t understand whats going on there, seems like github pages doesn’t want to work with bootstrap properly.

Link to the project: https://github.com/formlessfall/slmcarports 
Link to the hosted project on github pages: https://formlessfall.github.io/slmcarports/timber_decking.html

Please, help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have used jQuery which is not secure.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Github pages are secure but you are using **http** which is not secure. So in secure extension, all external urls should be secure.

Please use **https** it will work fine.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped! I also updated the jQuery version. The link I use now is <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"   integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>